# ubuntu 13.10 how to change nautilus title bar color

Tags: gtk3

I would like to know if I need to change the file nautilus.css in gtk3 theme folder or metacity.xml in metacity theme folder

I use ubuntu 13.10 in flashback mode

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the metacity xml files will apply your changes not only to nautilus but to all your windows.

To tweak nautilus elements, modify its css file in the active gtk3 theme folder.